Is it possible to hide application link on edit form
I want to hide the highlighted link on edit form because it exposes list to user. Is it possible using sharepoint out of the box? Users need to edit their applications as it is a business rule but clicking on the middle part takes them to the list which we don't want.


Unfortunately, it is not possible to hide the application link on the edit form using SharePoint out of the box.
You could consider create a request on the Developer Platform so Microsoft can look into this.

I tried adding a new page and embedding the form on it, then added a script editor web part to hide that highlighted part but it doesn't really work. Not sure why not.
